# subtract two column from different table and group by id and id

Tags: mysql

after two week search i couldn't write this query please help me

```
NOTE
  TABLE 1 sum(quantity_box) group by id_p and id_w
  TABLE 2 sum(quantity_box) group by id_p and id_w
then
  TABLE1.sum(quantity_box)- TABLE2.sum(quantity_box) where id_p = id_p and id_w = id_w
```

table 1 ) wherehouseproduct_add   id = id_w

```
id | name
10 | warehouse1
20 | warehouse2
```

table2) wherehouse_products

```
id | id_w |id_p |quantity_box
1  |  10  | 2   |  10  
2  |  10  | 2   |  50  
3  |  20  | 3   |  100
4  |  20  | 1   |  20
5  |  20  | 1   |  10
6  |  10  | 1   |  10
7  |  10  | 3   |  10
```

table3) wherehouse_products_sell

```
 id | id_w |id_p |quantity_box
 1  |  10  | 2   |  50  
 2  |  20  | 3   |  30
 3  |  20  | 1   |  20
```

table4) products

```
id_p | product_name
1    | snack
2    | watebottle
3    | headphone
```

i want to output like

```
id_w | id_p  | product_name| total_quantity_box
10   | 1     | snack       |10
10   | 2     | watebottle  |10   
10   | 3     | headphone   |10
20   | 1     | snack       |10
20   | 2     | watebottle  |10   
20   | 3     | headphone   |70
```

Comment: Small note the naming conventions are important to understand what "id" refers to which "table" without having to check each time in the database. It avoids confusion when writing code. It's just a little tip ^^

Comment: for id_w 20 and id_p 1 quantity should be 0 as per your criteria and in expected result you have specified 20 ?

Comment: thanks  you @FoxCy   =]]]]

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid mybad sorry

Answer (score 0):

Calculate each type of sum individually in sub selects and join them as per your criteria then do your calculations in outer select

```
select wp.id_w,
wp.id_p,
wp.quantity - wps.quantity total_quantity_box
from
(select id_w,id_p,sum(quantity_box) quantity from wherehouse_products group by id_w,id_p) wp
join
(select id_w,id_p,sum(quantity_box) quantity from wherehouse_products_sell group by id_w,id_p) wps
using(id_w,id_p)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39ff2a/5)